# HTML5 nested list text size

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

Seems in Chrome that if I assign font-size:1.2em to list elements and have nested lists like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Normal size text 1.2em</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>This text gets bigger</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The text automatically gets bigger but if I set font-size:12px it doesn't, anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Can you setup a demo on http://jsfiddle.net and also post you CSS here?

Comment: You surely have some CSS that is conflicting.

Answer (score 2):

em is relative, that means a list in a list inherits the parents list size and makes it bigger by 1.2em

Comment: Thanks, I assumed setting 1.2em would inherit from the browser default, not inherit from its parent, thanks.